# how to open jQuery UI dialog with AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

On my web page I have a jQuery UI Dialog.  When I click the button (create new user) it opens a new window. My question is how can I open that window with an AJAX request?

It would be nice to open the dialog-form from another page. For example: `dialog.html`

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
  <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

  <form>
  <fieldset>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
  </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

You can see full code in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jXpNT):

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can define your dialog like this :

```
function showUrlInDialog(url){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'dialog.html',
    success: function(data) {
      $("#dialog-form").load(data).dialog({modal:true}).dialog('open');
    }
  });
}
```

And define the current markup that is inside dialog-form div, into a new page called dialog.html. Call the above written function on the button click event. I hope this is what you needed.

Comment: It worked, thank you. One question: Ajax loads that window while clicking? Or loads before? If I will write sql query into dialog, will my php page read the sql query when I enter the site or will read after when I click button?

Comment: It is supposed to load before as far as I think. The page will be requested as soon as the code I mentioned above runs. You can cross check that by taking a look at the fiddler trace. Hence the SQL query is also supposed to run when the page loads and not when the button is clicked.

Comment: Okay, man, I should write a couple of sql query into dialog. And I want php sends sql reguests when I start clicking the button. After clicking is writed: Please wait, loading ... after a few seconds is opened dialog. You can see it on Facebook, when user wants to see like list..after a few seconds is opened dialog and show all likes.

Comment: This is what will help you.. http://8raystech.com/2011/06/28/how-to-dynamic-content-in-a-jquery-ui-dialog-by-loading-a-url-via-ajax

Comment: For me `$("#dialog-form").html(data).dialog({modal: true}).dialog('open');`

Comment: just use .load(your_url); sample:
$("#dialog-form").load("dialog.html").dialog({modal:true}).dialog('open');

Answer (score 7):

I think this is a simpler version of the answer:

```
$("#the-button").click(function(){
  $("#dialog").dialog({modal: true}).dialog('open')).load("dialog.html")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For me **.load** is not working. So I used,

```
function showUrlInDialog(url){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'dialog.html',
    success: function(data) {
      $("#dialog-form").html(data).dialog({modal:true}).dialog('open');
    }
  });
}
```